# Select top n elements from list of lists in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, nested-lists

I'm trying to create a new list of lists from an existing one. I'm trying to select top N values from the inner lists and output a new list of lists. The current list looks like this:

```
[[('with', -3.608809242675524),
  ('cruz', -3.6553518286125546),
  ('rt', -2.962847001582534)],
[ ('his', -2.9577717646107025),
  ('is', -2.9627189839205403),
  ('to', -2.968666793195209)]]
```

Now I want to take this as an input and output the top 1 element from each list. The real list is longer and has more than 2 lists, and I would want to take top N elements. The output should look like this:

```
[[('with', -3.608809242675524)],
[('his', -2.9577717646107025)]]
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: So when you say "top", you really mean "first", right? Normally, "top" implies value comparisons, but it looks like you just want to slice off elements beyond the Nth, correct?

Comment: What's the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a list comprehension with slicing of the inner lists.

```
result = [l[:N] for l in original_list]
```

Comment: Or for in-place behavior: `for lst in original_list: del lst[N:]`

Comment: Yeah, but he said he wants to create a new list.

Comment: In my case, I did result_top_N = [l for l in list[:N]] because I needed top N elements from a list of Strings